# soap.findAll('table',class_='wikitable sortable') is not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just wrote a simple query to parse data in an html page. But i get an empty list of results even though such a class exists in the page.
Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
wiki =      "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia`enter code here`
req = urllib.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urllib.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" })
print (table)
```

Comment: After fixing the wrong `urllib` calls, the code retrieves a table. I am using `python 3.4.3` and `bs4 4.2.1`. What versions are you using?

Comment: In question title you use `findAll` but in code it's `find`

Comment: I am using python 3.4.3 and beautiful soap 4. Can you please share the corrected urllib calls?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full class name, it should work:

```
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be oversimplifying this but, `sortable` and `jquery-tablesorter` are like keywords.

You should only specify the `class` as `wikitable`